# Resolve this java algorithm for Dice for Risk game

Tags: java, algorithm, random, dice

like in risk game I have to roll dices, but I don't want to use the `Random.nextInt()` method for each roll.
For some reasons I have already the result of the attack, and I want to simply generate the values of the dices.
In risk game the dices are ordered and compared singly:
**For example:** if attack rolls 3 dices and defense rolls 2 dices and these are the results:
[4, 3, 5] - [3, 5]
The attack lost 1 tank and the defense lost 1 tanks because:
[5, 4, 3] - [5, 3]
5 = 5 (the attack loses in case of a tie)
 4 > 3 (the defense loses)
3 (the third dice is useless in this case)
This is the input code:

```
int diceForAttack = StringUtils.nextInt(3) + 1;
int diceForDefense = StringUtils.nextInt(3) + 1;
//prints: attack Vs. defense
System.out.println(String.format("%d Vs. %d", diceForAttack, diceForDefense));

int maxLost = Math.min(diceForAttack, diceForDefense);
int attackLoses = StringUtils.nextInt(maxLost + 1);
int defenseLoses = maxLost - attackLoses;
//prints:
//Attack lost x
//Defense lost y
System.out.println(String.format("Attack lost %d\nDefense lost %d", attackLoses, defenseLoses));

//Now I want to generate two arrays
//such that the dice respect the values attackLoses and defenseLoses
int[] attack = new int[diceForAttack];
int[] defense= new int[diceForDefense];
...
...
...
```

**The question is:**
Since I already know how many tanks will lose the attack and the defense.
How can I generate two arrays such that the dice respect the values attackLoses and defenseLoses?

Comment: Why aren't you generating the dice rolls and then determining the result based on the rules?

Comment: add a tie (random value, same for attack and defense) for each tank lost by attack (it does not even really have to be random. 1 is fine). Add a > for each tank lost by defense. 2 and 1, for instance. or one random on [1-5], the other on [x-6].

Comment: @rgettman Because I have many dice type from Easy to Realistic. Where Realistic uses the probabilities based on the rules. But Easy mode favors the attack.

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks. I try to implement your suggests, then I will let you know.

Comment: For "Easy" mode, you could make a tie favor the attacker instead of the defender.

Comment: @rgettman I know what you mean, but I have to do this way

Comment: @MDSRISIK: you say you have to do it this way, but the user will notice at some point that some dice combination are more frequent than other. unless you go deep into the math of it to make sure that your dice rolls are evenly distributed despite being pre-arranged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean, easy way to handle problems like this is to reroll the dice until you get the outcome that you want. The downside is that, if the requested outcome is unlikely (or even impossible), then it will take a while, but that seems as though it wouldn't be an issue here.